# Prolog ¿Cómo imprimir una matriz o arreglo bidimensional?

Tags: prolog

¿Cómo crear un programa en *Prolog*, que defina un predicado llamado matriz y que sea capaz de recibir 1 o 2 argumentos? Si lo consultamos con un argumento se imprimirá una matriz cuadrada.

Si lo consultamos con dos argumentos, el primero definirá el número de filas y el segundo será el número de columnas.

Debe mostrar su resultado de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes hasta el momento?¿Con qué problemas te estás encontrando?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español, será más fácil y rápido obtener una respuesta si muestras tu esfuerzo, hasta donde haz logrado avanzar en la programación y qué problemas estás enfrentado.

Comment: Sólo encuentro ejemplos para sumar interactuar con matrices, por ejemplo sumar matrices, elemento de una matriz, pero no el de imprimirla o crearla.

Comment: Para lo que pides ni siquiera hace falta una matriz. Por lo que parece, sólo se muestran números en forma de matriz, ¿no?

Comment: si , no se necesita la implementación de la matriz, se podría hacer con un contador y solo faltaría acomodar la manera de imprimir , y en eso tengo problemas y muchas gracias por la bienvenida

Comment: Pensaba Matriz(X):- X > 0, agregar un contador , y agregar un salto de linea cada que un valor Y % X == 0. me falta cómo expresarlo en prolog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una posible solución. No sé cómo de bien estará o si te servirá (llevo sin hacer programación lógica/declarativa desde la universidad, así que puede que me haya salido la vena funcional más de lo que debiese). Lo habría basado más en el código que ya tenías, pero lo borraste tan pronto que no pude copiarlo.

Esto eso lo que hace:

- Si la matriz se llama sólo con un parámetro, se duplica ese parámetro para que sea cuadrada.
- Si la matriz se llama con dos parámetros:

  - Se calcula MAX que será el múltiplo de ambos parámetros (que será el número máximo de ciclos)
  - Se llama al predicado muestraMatriz con los parámetros 1 (primer valor a mostrar), MAX (el número de ciclos que faltan por ejecutar), y el número de elementos por fila de la matriz.
- muestraMatriz realizará las siguientes acciones:

  - mostrará el número que toque (primer parámetro)
  - calculará el módulo del valor actual para ver si toca romper línea
  - actualizará los valores del Siguiente y el contador (MAX)
  - se llamará de manera recursiva con los valores Siguiente, MAX y números por fila (no cambia)
- Cuando se llame a muestraMatriz y el segundo parámetro sea 0 (ya se hayan realizado todas las iteraciones), se termina la ejecución.

Y el código sería así (lo puedes ver [ejecutándose aquí](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/muestraMatriz.pl)):

```
muestraMatriz(_, 0, _).

muestraMatriz(A, B, C):-
    write(A),
    write(" "),
    M is A mod C,
    rompeLinea(M),
    Siguiente is A + 1,
    MAX is B - 1,
    muestraMatriz(Siguiente, MAX, C).

rompeLinea(0):-
    nl.

rompeLinea(_).

matriz(N):-
    matriz(N,N).

matriz(M,N):-
    MAX is M * N,
    muestraMatriz(1, MAX, N).
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Alvario tu solución fue perfecta, una observación cuando ejecutaba en prolog tu código no tenia fin me imprimia la matriz sin un final, como prolog trabaja desde arriba hasta abajo entonces el limitador

Comment: muestraMatriz(_, 0, _):-!. tendría que ir arriba de muestraMatriz(A, B, C):-..... ; y el signo de corte también lo quite por que era innecesario, y así ya imprimió correctamente, pero tú te hiciste cargo de la lógica y te lo agradezco mucho, ese detalle tal vez lo escapaste por que en ese IDE web no lo mostraba, fue hasta que lo probe en SWI-PROLOG.

Comment: @Zmjc He actualizado el código con los cambios que sugieres. Gracias por el comentario, está bien aprender algo nuvo :)